# How can I hide the storyboard overview in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, storyboard

Since a few updates ago, Xcode shows an overview of all scenes in a storyboard. While it may be helpful for navigating a large storyboard, I often find that it gets in the way of what I really want to see: UI elements. Is there any option to hide it? I've tried right-clicking but to no avail.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called the minimap, and you can toggle its visibility from the Editor menu.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to using the Editor menu is to use the editor options button.

[image]

Then from this menu

[image]